# How get Currency Symbole ftrom the LocalID in SharePoint Online using JSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-jsom

How get Currency Symbole ftrom the LocalID in SharePoint Online using JSOM?

I have a localeId which is set to 2057 as English (United Kingdom) and now I want to fetch its currency symbol uisng JSOM.

Can someone point me some link for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can find currency symbol from `get_localeId` derived from regional settings.

Below is the code to retrieve Id for the site collection and retrieve country from  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/currency-element-regional-settings) link

```
(function(){
  var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();
  var regionalSettings = web.get_regionalSettings();
  context.load(regionalSettings);
  context.executeQueryAsync(
     function() {
         console.log(regionalSettings.get_localeId());        
     },
     function(sender,args){
         console.log(args.get_message());
     }
  );    
})();
```